# How to get the median of different intervals of dataframe based on label name?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

So I have a DataFrame with two columns, one with label names (df['Labels']) and the other with int values (df['Volume']).

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Labels': 
['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','C','C','C','C','C'],
                   'Volume':[10,40,20,20,50,60,40,50,50,60,10,10,10,10,20,20,10,20,80,90,90,80,100]})
```

I would like to identify intervals where my labels change and then calculate the median on the column 'Volume' for each of these intervals. Later I should replace every value of column 'Volume' by the respective median of each interval.

In case of label A, I would like to have the median for both intervals.

Here is how my DataFrame should looks like:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Labels':['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','C','C','C','C','C'],
                    'Volume':[20,20,20,20,50,50,50,50,50,50,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,90,90,90,90,90]})
```

Comment: `df.groupby(df.Labels.ne(df.Labels.shift()).cumsum()).transform('median')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to `groupby` the blocks and transform median:

```
blocks = df['Labels'].ne(df['Labels'].shift()).cumsum()
df['group_median'] = df['Volume'].groupby(blocks).transform('median')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Series.cumsum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) + [Series.shift()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) to create groups using [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and then use `transform`

```
df['Volume']=df.groupby(df['Labels'].ne(df['Labels'].shift()).cumsum())['Volume'].transform('median')
print(df)
```

---

```
   Labels  Volume
0       A      20
1       A      20
2       A      20
3       A      20
4       B      50
5       B      50
6       B      50
7       B      50
8       B      50
9       B      50
10      A      10
11      A      10
12      A      10
13      A      10
14      A      10
15      A      10
16      A      10
17      A      10
18      C      90
19      C      90
20      C      90
21      C      90
22      C      90
```